# How to use map() in vue.js 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Im start learning vue.js and ive got some troubles. I need to use dictionary analog in js. Its called map. but i dont know where i should define it. I need to use it in `checkDevices()` method and in HTML code

P.S. Sorry for my English

```
export default {
    data: () => ({
   }),
   devicesList: new map(
    "varNameOne", false,
    "varNameTwo", false,
    "varNameThree", false,
    ),
    methods: {
        async checkDevices () {
            let response = await axios.get(`/some/api`)
            console.log("res.data: ", response.data);

            devicesList.forEach((values, keys) => {
            console.log("Key: ", keys, "Value: ", values);
            })
        }
    }
}
```

ive trying to define it before `export default` like this: `let devicesList = new map(...);`, but it doesnt work.

In `` axios.get(`/some/api`) `` ive got response frome server with data (response.data):

```
device1: true
device2: false
device1: true
```

I need take it frome response in key-value pair for using in UI like

- device1 connected
- device2 disconnected
- divice3 connected

Comment: Please describe what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: Please edit your question with Input and output. What is the role of AXIOS response here as you are not using response anywhere?

Comment: @Neha axios is just lib for REST api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the JSON of your Axios response so you need to update checkDevices function to match the key values. there is no need to use map above export default. you can do this in mounted function.

```
export default {
    data:function(){
        return {
            devicesList:[]
        }
    },
    mounted:function(){
        this.devicesList = new Map();
        this.devicesList.set('device1', false);
        this.devicesList.set('device2', false);
        this.devicesList.set('device3', false);
    },
    methods: {
        async checkDevices () {
            let response = await axios.get(`/some/api`)
            console.log("res.data: ", response.data);

            devicesList.forEach((values, keys) => {
                console.log("Key: ", keys, "Value: ", values);
                //Please Use YOUR RESPONSE.data here to update the device List
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to use it like dictionary key-value

Comment: @voidsMark maybe reading a bit of that one could help you: https://javascript.info/array-methods